# Multiple bars of the same data on the same y-axis in Bokeh

Tags: python, charts, visualization, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh's hbar_stack() method in order to make a stacked horizontal bar chart.

In Matthew Rocklin's post [here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/12/dask-dataframes), the very first chart plots how long tasks take on different worker cores. It plots "read-block" and "pandas_read_text."

I was wondering how you could get multiple bars of a phase (ex. "read-block") onto the same y-axis when using hbar_stack(). Any general advice behind how this chart is created would also be helpful.